# Is it ok to use 'this' in final instance variable declaration?

Tags: java, android, final

Is it OK to use the `this` keyword in a `final` instance variable declaration/initialization in Java?

Like this:

```
private final SomeClass foo = new SomeClass(this);
```

It worked when I tried it out. And since it is not a `static` variable I guess it should be referring to a particular instance. But I felt unsure if it is advisable or not so therefore I wanted to ask here.

Edit:
The main class is an Android Activity class, and the SomeClass-instance needs this Activity as Context.

Comment: I think here its matter what is "this" ?

Comment: What do you think? Why could it not be ok?

Comment: The question that arises is why you need such a coupling of two classes. But basically there is no problem with this construct.

Comment: It is from a Android Activity class, and I need the Activity Context (this) in the final instance I declare.

I don't know, I'm not used to using the final keyword and initializing variables before the constructor. I guess thats why I felt unsure about it..

Comment: @Absurd-Mind Thanks for your input! Yes I will think a bit about avoiding the coupling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is "technically valid" to do this. Indeed, `this` refers to a particular instance - namely, the instance that contains the instance of `SomeClass`.

But I would **not** recommend to do this in general. The exact behavior and state of the `this` that is passed to the constructor depends on subtle details. Consider the following example:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass(DangerousSelfReference dangerousSelfReference)
    {
        System.out.println("State: ");
        System.out.println("   a: "+dangerousSelfReference.getA());
        System.out.println("   b: "+dangerousSelfReference.getB());
        System.out.println("   c: "+dangerousSelfReference.getC());
        System.out.println("   d: "+dangerousSelfReference.getD());
        System.out.println(" ref: "+dangerousSelfReference.getRef());
    }
}

public class DangerousSelfReference
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DangerousSelfReference d = new DangerousSelfReference();
    }

    private String a;
    private String b = "b";
    private final SomeClass ref = new SomeClass(this);
    private final String c = "c";
    private String d = "d";

    DangerousSelfReference()
    {
        a = "a";
    }

    String getA()
    {
        return a;
    }
    String getB()
    {
        return b;
    }
    String getC()
    {
        return c;
    }
    String getD()
    {
        return d;
    }
    SomeClass getRef()
    {
        return ref;
    }
}
```

I assume that this could make a neat job interview question, because predicting the output is hard. Surprisingly, it prints

```
State: 
   a: null
   b: b
   c: c
   d: null
 ref: null
```

Notice that the `final` variable `c` is initialized, but the non-final variable `d` is **not** intialized yet. In contrast to that, the non-final variable `b` (that is declared *before* the `SomeClass` instance) is already intitialized.

Such subtelities are always questionable, and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: Thanks! Good example! I think i get it.

Answer (score 3):

```
private final SomeClass foo = new SomeClass(this);
private int bar = 42;
```

The SomeClass constructor will find a `bar` with 0.

So it is not so fine.

Comment: Thanks, short and simple explaination!

Answer (score 1):

My first concern is : why would you need this ?

Generally, I would not recommend this as it could potentially be dangerous in more complex scenarios, where `SomeClass` construction depends on certain state of passed `this` object.

Consider, for example :

```
class SomeClass {
    private Foo foo;
    SomeClass(Foo foo) {
         this.foo = foo;
         // do something based on state of foo
         // such as call
         int len = foo.myString.length(); // <- this will throw NPE, because
         // foo.myString is still null as Foo() constructor wasn't called yet
    }
}
```

and then your Foo class:

```
class Foo {
    String myString = null;

    Foo() {/*constructor 1, perhaps calling init()*/
        init();
    }
    Foo(...params) {/*constructor 2*/}

    private void init() {
        // some initialization
        myString = "test String";
    }    


    // Note: this constructor is called before any of Foo's 
    // constructos are invoked
    // thus passed Foo "this" object is not initialized yet 
    // (contains defaults for all fields)
    private final SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass(this);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

yes it is fine.

as it has nothing to do with the `final` keyword of the Instance variable.
what you are doing is passing the enclosing class' object to the constructor of `SomeClass`