# What exactly are the dangers of passing 'this' from a Java constructor?

Tags: java

So it seems that it's a bad idea to pass `this` from a constructor in Java.

```
class Foo {
    Foo() {
        Never.Do(this);
    }
}
```

My simple question is: Why?

There are some related questions on Stackoverflow, but none of them give a comprehensive list of issues that may arise.

For instance, [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419410/passing-this-in-java-constructor), which is asking for a workaround to this problem, [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2419442/27862) states:

> For example if your class has a final (non-static) field, then you can usually depend on it being set to a value and never changing.
>
> When the object you look at is currently executing its constructor, then that guarantee no longer holds true.

How is that?

Also, I understand that subclassing is a big issue, because the superclass constructor is always called before the subclass constructor, and that may cause problems.

Besides, I read that [Java Memory Model (JMM) issues such as differences in visibility across threads and memory access reordering](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0618/index.html#2) may arise, but no details on that.

What other problems may occur and can  you elaborate on the abovementioned issues?

Comment: As always, a bit of code is worth 1024 words...

Comment: The caller using the reference of `this` may require something from it before it's fully initialized...

Comment: You shouldn't allow `this` to escape the constructor before the object is fully constructed because it will lead to an *undefined* state of the Object. Other methods might work on the same half-constructed object.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: That looks like an answer. :-)

Comment: An overview and summary what can go wrong is shown in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23264885/3182664 (shown for declarations, but for constructors, there are analogous caveats)

Comment: In cases like this it is best to have a real-life analogy. Say you're building a ship and halfway through the construction process you put the ship in the water. Can you be sure the hull is complete so it can already float?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Basically, you already enumerate the bad things that can happen, so you partly answer your own question already. I will provide the details for the things you mention:

### Handing out `this` before initializing final fields

> For example if your class has a final (non-static) field, then you can
>   usually depend on it being set to a value and never changing.
>
> When the object you look at is currently executing its constructor,
>   then that guarantee no longer holds true.
>
> How is that?

Quite simple: If you hand out `this` before setting a `final` field, then it will not be set, yet:

```
class X{
    final int i;
    X(){
        new Y(this); // ouch, don't do this!
        i = 5;
    }
}

class Y{
    Y(X x){
        assert(x.i == 5);//This assert should be true, since i is final field, but it fails here
    }
}
```

Quite simple, right? Class `Y` sees a `X` with an uninitialized `final` field. This is a big no-no!

Java usually ensures that a `final` field is initialized exactly once and is not read before it is initialized. This guarantee vanishes once you leak `this`.

*Note that the same problem also happens for non-`final` fields which is equally bad. However, people are more surprised if a `final` field is found uninitialized.*

### Subclassing

The problems with subclassing are quite similar to the one above: Base classes get initialized before derived classes, so if you leak a `this` reference in the base class constructor, you leak an object that has not yet initialized its derived fields. This can 
become very nasty in case of polymorphic methods, as this example shows:

```
class A{
    static void doFoo(X x){
        x.foo();
    }
}

class X{
    X(){
        A.doFoo(this); // ouch, don't do this!
    }

    void foo(){
        System.out.println("Leaking this seems to work!");
    }

}

class Y extends X {
     PrintStream stream;

     Y(){
         this.stream = System.out;
     }

     @Overload // Polymorphism ruins everything!
     void foo(){
         // NullPointerException; stream not yet initialized 
         stream.println("Leaking + Polymorphism == NPE");      
     }

}
```

So as you see, there is a class `X` with a `foo` method. `X` is leaked to `A` in its constructor and `A` calls `foo`. For `X` classes, this works just fine. But for `Y` classes, a `NullPointerException` is thrown. The reason is that `Y` overrides `foo` and uses one of its fields (`stream`) in it. Since `stream` is not initialized yet when `A` calls `foo`, you receive the exception.

This example shows the next problem with leaking this: *Even if your base class might work just fine when leaking `this`, a class inheriting from your base class (which may not be written by you but someone else who is not aware of leaked `this`) may blow everything up.*

### Leaking `this` to yourself

This section does not exactly talk about an own kind of problem, but a thing to bear in mind: Even calling one of your own methods can be considered as a leaked `this`, as it brings similar problems as a reference leaked to another class. For example, consider the previous example with a different `X` constructor:

```
    X(){
        // A.doFoo();
        foo(); // ouch, don't do this!
    }
```

Now, we do not leak `this` to `A` but we leak it to ourself by calling `foo`. Again, the same bad things happen: A class `Y` that overrides `foo()` and uses one of its own fields will wreak havok.

Now consider our first example with the `final` field. Again, leaking to yourself via a method may allow for finding a `final` field uninitialized:

```
class X{
   final int i;
   X(){ 
      foo();
      i = 5;
   }

   void foo(){
      assert(i == 5); // Fails, of course
   }
}
```

Of course, this example is quite constructed. Every programmer will notice that first calling `foo` and then setting `i` is wrong. But now consider inheritance again: Your `X.foo()` method might not even use `i`, so it is fine to be called before initializing `i`. However, a subclass might override `foo()` and use `i` in it, again breaking everything.

Also note that an overridden `foo()` method might leak `this` even further by passing it to other classes. So while we only intended to leak `this` to ourselves by calling `foo()` a subclass might override `foo()` and publish `this` to the whole world.

Whether calling one's own methods is considered a leaked `this` might be debatable. However, as you see, it brings similar problems, so I wanted to discuss it here, even if many people may not agree that calling an own method is considered a leaked `this`.

If you really need to call your own methods in a constructor, then either use only `final` or `static` methods, as these cannot be overridden by an innocent derived class.

### Concurrency

Final fields in the Java memory model possess a nice property: They can be read concurrently without locking. The JVM has to ensure that even concurrent unlocked access will always see a fully initialized `final` field. This can be done, by example, by adding a memory barrier to the end of a constructor that assigns final fields. **However, this guarantee vanishes once you hand out `this` too early.** Again, an example:

```
class X{
    final int i;
    X(Y y){
        i = 5;
        y.x = this; // ouch, don't do this!
    }
}

class Y{
    public static Y y;
    public X x;
    Y(){
        new X(this);
    }
}

//... Some code in one thread
{
    Y.y = new Y();
}

//... Some code in another thread
{
    assert(Y.y.x.i == 5); // May fail!
}
```

As you see, we again hand out `this` too early, but only **after** initializing `i`. So in a single threaded environment, everything is fine. But now enter concurrency: We create a static `Y` (which receives the tainted `X` instance) in one thread and access it in a second thread. Now, the assertion may again fail, because the compiler or the CPU out of order execution are now **allowed to reorder** the assignment of `i = 5` and the assignment of `Y.y = new Y()`.

To make things clearer, suppose the JVM would inline all calls, thus, the code

```
{
        Y.y = new Y();
}
```

would be first inlined to (`rX` are local registers):

```
{
        r1 = 'allocate memory for Y' // Constructor of Y
        r1.x = new X(r1);            // Constructor of Y
        Y.y = r1;
}
```

now we would also inline the call to `new X()`:

```
{
        r1 = 'allocate memory for Y' // constructor of Y
        r2 = 'allocate memory for X' // constructor of X
        r2.i = 5;                    // constructor of X
        r1.x = r2;                   // constructor of X
        Y.y = r1;
}
```

Until now, everything is fine. But now, the reordering is allowed to happen. We (i.e., the JVM or the CPU) reorder `r2.i = 5` to the end:

```
{
        r1 = 'allocate memory for Y' // 1.
        r2 = 'allocate memory for X' // 2.
        r1.x = r2;                   // 3.
        Y.y = r1;                    // 4.
        r2.i = 5;                    // 5.
}
```

Now, we can observe the wrong behaviour: Consider thread 1 executes all steps up to `4.` and then is interrupted (before the `final` field is set!). Now, thread 2 executes all code and thus its `assert(Y.y.x == 5);` fails.

### What other problems may occur

Basically, the three problems you mentioned and I explained above are the worst ones. Of course, there are many different facets in which these problems can occur so one could construct thousands of examples. As long as your program is single threaded, handing out this early *might* be okay (but don't do it anyway!). As soon as concurrency comes into play, never ever do it, you will get strange behaviours because the JVM is basically allowed to reorder things as desired in this case. Instead of remembering the gory details of various concrete problems that can happen, simply remember the two conceptual things that can happen:

- A constructor usually first constructs an object thoroughly and then hands it to the caller. A `this` that escapes the constructor represents a partly constructed object and usually you never ever want to have partly constructed objects, because they are hard to reason about (see my first example). Especially when inheritance comes into play, things get even more complicated. Simply rember: *Leaking `this` + inheritance = Here be dragons.*
- The memory model gives up most guarantees once you hand out `this` in a constructor, so crazy reorderings might yield very strange executions that are almost impossible to debug. Simply rember: *Leaking `this` + concurreny = Here be dragons.*

Comment: Okay, for some reason I thought final fields could be initialized even after construction. Needless to say I am new to Java ;)

Comment: This is a great answer, but could you add an example of an issue with subclassing?

Comment: @Pumbaa80: Added a section for subclassing, right after the first one.

Comment: @Pumbaa80: Also added a section for leaking this to yourself, which is also a problem that should be mentioned and is often overlooked.